# Eclipse C++ Indexing Boost Takes Forever

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost

If I include both headers:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp>
```

It takes forever. In this way, what I am doing is everytime I have to comment one by one, for example:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
//#include <boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp>
```

and let it index as showed in the Figure bellow. Then I remove the comment and let it index for the second one.

[image: Figure 1]

**What should I do to fix it? I tryed everything (even other eclipse versions).**

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: If "try everything" means "using different versions of the same thing"... I don't think you should expect big differences. I can assure you that it's perfectly normal for Eclipse CDT indexing to take forever. I use Vim + YouCompleteMe and it's quite

Comment: I concur.  It take forever to index boost on Eclipe compared to everything else I've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like updating gcc/g++ on Ubuntu can solve the problem.

I don't know the reason but, seems like that with the gcc/g++ version that comes with Ubuntu 16.04 this problem may appear. The problem was occurring on both my laptop and at my virtual ubuntu on my desktop pc.

Before updating gcc and g++ I had to comment all the boost libraries, and uncomment one per time to allow the indexing procedure to process on per time.

After the updating, the gcc to 7.2 I made several tests with different projects and the indexing is occurring normally without problems.